# Why is AWS Cognito (SNS) not sending message to verify user attribute?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-sns

I am having trouble getting SNS to send a verification code when I am trying to verify a user attribute. In this case, I am trying to verify a user's `phone_number`.

My SNS account is in sandbox mode; I have verified that I'm able to successfully send myself a test SNS message from the AWS console.

When making the request from within my app (node) I am getting the following `200` response:

```
{
    "CodeDeliveryDetails": {
        "Destination": "+*******1234",
        "DeliveryMedium": "SMS",
        "AttributeName": "phone_number"
    }
}
```

Although I don't actually ever receive a text message. I have seen that a possible solution is to increase the spend limit. However, this is the first few messages I've sent so I don't think that is my issue.

I can see in the SNS page that I have 4 messages sent, 3 failed (the successful was my test message). Is there a place to look at logs within the SNS context?

How can I find out why my messages aren't sending when making a seemingly successfuly request to `cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.verifyUserAttribute`

Comment: You can collect information about successful and unsuccessful SMS message deliveries by enabling Amazon SNS to write to Amazon CloudWatch Logs. For each SMS message that you send, Amazon SNS writes a log that includes the message price, the success or failure status, the reason for failure (if the message failed), the message dwell time, and other information. Detailed instructions can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sms_stats_cloudwatch.html#sns-viewing-cloudwatch-logs).

Comment: When your AWS account is in the sandbox, Amazon SNS imposes some restrictions. For example, you can send text messages to a maximum of 10 phone numbers that you have **verified** with Amazon SNS. When you're in the sandbox, Amazon Cognito can't send messages to your users' phone numbers.

Comment: Ah—awesome. I'm able to see the failure now. "Phone carrier has blocked this message". This should be a fun one. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Following up here, Arpit Jain really helped point me in the right direction. Because I was in sandbox in my AWS SMS account, I could only send to my verified phone number.

I had my number verified within my sandbox, but because of some recent regulation updates (please correct me if I am wrong), I need to verify my toll-free number (the number sending my verification code) within Pinpoint.

Pinptoint provides a toll-free registration form that I needed to fill out and provide my use case. It took a bit, but once it was approved, I am now successfully receiving the verification code from Cognito.